# Generic base class

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, generic-programming

I am doing a customization from an existing library, which has following structure:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public Method1();
    public Method2();
}
public class A : BaseClass
{
    public Method1();
    public Method2();
}
public class B : BaseClass
{
    public Method1();
    public Method2();
}
public class C : BaseClass
{
    public Method1();
    public Method2();
}
```

The above are code that **I cannot change**.

Now, I need to cumtom A, B, C. but ALL changes inside each inheritances are totally SAME. logic and code are totally same changes.

```
public class BaseClass1 : BaseClass
{
    public override Method1(); //some logic changed comparing to base
}
public class A1 : A
{
    public override Method1(); //Changes are totally  same with BaseClass1 
}
public class B1 : B
{
    public override Method1(); //Changes are totally  same with BaseClass1 
}
public class C1 : C
{
    public override Method1(); //Changes are totally  same with BaseClass1 
}
```

All code are duplicated, copy-pasted in each class.

My Question is: How can I avoid copy-pasted code??

This code doesn't work clearly:

```
public class BaseClass1<T> : T where T: BaseClass  //Base class cannot be T
{
    public override Method1(); 
    public override Method2(); 
}
```

The reason I don't want to duplicate code is that there are C,D,E,F and so on inheritances.

Comment: You can't do multiple inheritance in C#, so you either change the base class (which for some reason you can't) or you will have to live with some duplication. You could minimise the duplication by having the bulk of that code in a single class and calling it from A, B, C etc.

Comment: Thanks @DavidG. I thought there is a way to avoid to duplicate 5+ mothods in 5+ classes. Probably, I will send a request to the library maker to make classes generic. For temparary,  I'm using exactly your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

As one option you could use a variation of the decorator pattern, 
(the exact library signatures are unknown so I have added examples where methods are overridden or hidden)
example below:

```
// original libary code
public class BaseClass
{
    public virtual string Method1() => "m1 of base";
    public string Method2() => "m2 of base";
}
public class A : BaseClass
{
    public override string Method1() => "m1 A";
    public string Method2() => "m2 A";
}
public class B : BaseClass
{
    public override string Method1() => "m1 B";
    public string Method2() => "m2 B";
}
public class C : BaseClass
{
    public override string Method1() => "m1 C";
    public string Method2() => "m2 C";
}


// methods to be overridden
public interface IMethodOfBase
{
    void Method1();
    void Method2();
}

// common behaviour
public class Decorator:IMethodOfBase
{
    private BaseClass b;

    public Decorator(BaseClass b)
    {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public void Method1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"overridden behaviour in one place {b.Method1()}");
    }

    public void Method2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"overridden behaviour in one place {b.Method2()}");
    }
}

// example usage
public class WorkLoad
{
    private List<Decorator> _work; 

    public WorkLoad()
    {
        _work = new List<Decorator>
        {
            new Decorator(new A()),
            new Decorator(new B()),
            new Decorator(new C()) //etc
        };
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        _work.ForEach( n =>
        {
            n.Method1();
            n.Method2();
        });
    }

}
```

and to run it

```
WorkLoad workLoad = new WorkLoad();
workLoad.DoWork();
```

and output:
overridden behaviour in one place m1 A

overridden behaviour in one place m2 of base

overridden behaviour in one place m1 B

overridden behaviour in one place m2 of base

overridden behaviour in one place m1 C

overridden behaviour in one place m2 of base